# How to scrape table data from an unloaded tab in a website in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data of the index from this [website](https://www.indiainfoline.com/markets/derivatives/rollover). I am trying to scrape the rollover data from the index tab but when I scrape the table its content shows as follow:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="derivatives_section table table-striped responsive dt-responsive nowrap derivatives_rollover_tbl" id="rollover_index_table" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Future<br/> Price</th>
<th>% Price<br/> Chg.</th>
<th>% OI<br/> Chg.</th>
<th>No. of Shares<br/> Rolled</th>
<th>% Rollover</th>
<th id="ro_idx_1">% Chg Rollover <br/> Vs. 1 Month Avg.</th>
<th>% Rollover <br/>Cost </th>
<th id="ro_idx_2">% Chg Rollover Cost <br/> Vs. 1 Month Avg.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
<td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Following is the code that produces the same result as above :

```
import requests
import json
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.indiainfoline.com/markets/derivatives/rollover#derivatives_index'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

request = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'rollover_index_table'})
tbody = table.find('tbody')
tr = tbody.find('tr')
td = tr.find_all('td')

print(td)
```

How Can I Scrape The Website's Index Tab Data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data comes from an API call returning json. You can create a dataframe of the data as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.indiainfoline.com/api/papi-call-api.php?url=/Derivative/Derivative.svc/FNO-Rollover/FUTSTK/?responsetype=json').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['response']['data']['FNORollOverList']['FNORollOverdata'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just explaining what @QHarr did. This website's content is dynamically generated. Which means the content gets rendered through with this Json file through JavaScript. You can see bellow the data is not loaded when you make the request with Bs4 and that's why you are unable to retrieve it.

```
                        <div class="bs-component deri_roll_main">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb0">
                                        <li id="stk_tab" class="active"><a href="#derivatives_stock" data-toggle="tab">Stock</a></li>
                                        <li id="idx_tab"><a href="#derivatives_index" data-toggle="tab">Index</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix hidden visible-xs gray_bdr_b"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 txt_left_m text-right">
                                    <div class="fill_exp_date w100p"><span>Expiry Date -</span> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="derivatives_stock">
                                <!-- <table id="derivatives_rollover_tbl" class="derivatives_rollover_tbl display nowrap" style="width:100%">-->
                                    <div class="tablepanel">
                                        <table class="derivatives_section table table-striped  responsive dt-responsive nowrap derivatives_rollover_tbl" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="rollover_stock_table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Script</th>
                                                <th >Future<br> Price</th>
                                                <th>% Price<br> Chg</th>
                                                <th>% OI<br> Chg</th>
                                                <th>No. of Shares<br> Rolled</th>
                                               <th>% Rollover</th>
                                                <th id="ro_stk_1">% Chg Rollover <br> VS 1 Month.Avg</th>
                                                <th>RO<br>Cost </th>
                                                <th id="ro_stk_2">% Chg Rollover <br> VS 1 Month.Avg</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                            <td><div class="text-line loading"></div></td>
                                        </tr>
```

One way to deal with this and the best in this scenario is to get the data straight from the API call. But this is not always possible. The second way is to use another tool that is Javascript capable and will render this data for you, like Selenium or Scrapy with Splash.